# Does Micrometer timer records when exception is thrown inside of the record block?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, timer, grafana, micrometer

Just a quick example:

```
fun main(): String? {
    val response: String? = null
    meterRegistry.timer("name").record {
        response = getResponse() // throws exception
    }
    return response
}
```

In that case getResponse() throws an exception and there is no catch in the main method.
Does it still record to grafana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/AbstractTimer.java#L156-L165)…

```java
@Override
public void record(Runnable f) {
    final long s = clock.monotonicTime();
    try {
        f.run();
    } finally {
        final long e = clock.monotonicTime();
        record(e - s, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }
}
```

…you can see that the timing is recorded also in case of exceptions (because of the `finally` block).